# Don't show .html component until all functions / data has been loaded. Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I have two methods inside ngOnInit as shown here:

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.getBugId(); // Get Id from URL 
    this.getBugInformation(); // Get the bug information from firebase, the bug that matches the ID passed in
}
```

`getBugId()`: basically gets the Id from the URL and assigns it to local variable.

`getBugInformation()`: calls a service, connects to firebase retrieves a single record matching the bugId I've passed in, and populates a class called Bug, this is working.

// Calls a method on a service which returns a promise.

```
 getBugInformation() {
    this.bugService
        .getBug3(this.bugId)
        .then(bug => {
            this.bugDetail = bug;
            this.configureForm();
        });
}
```

The issue I have is `this.configureForm();` this is basically populating fields inside FormControls which is then displayed on the .html page, the issue is my .html page appears before the functions have completed which results in 
    formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. being displayed within the console as an error, my question is.  How can I prevent the .html page from showing until,

`this.getBugInformation();` has completed
`this.configureForm();` has completed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use *ngIf on your html part which part you want to show late. *ngIf="firstfucntion"

Comment: Didn't work, instead it froze my browser. resulting in me having to force quit everything.

Comment: use a boolean display with initial value false. make it true only when your this.configureForm() function is ready. and in html use *ngIf="display". show me more code. i will tell you were you are doing mistake.. plnkr

Comment: @AmitSuhag all good, was originally calling the function, changed it to a boolean and works as explained! thanks for the help. Write it as the answer and I'll mark it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling two functions. to solving this issue you should create a boolean

```
display: boolean = false;
```

now in function `this.configureForm();` when your form is ready set `this.display = true;`

in your html part put all your forms which you want to show later in to a div block with *ngIf structural directive like this

```
<div *ngIf="display">
...... your code here 
</div>
```

thank you.